# how to parse a message from unix's curl method

Tags: http, unix, curl

I am writing a shell script for my class and am stuck on one part. I have this for example:

```
curl http://localhost:2300/messages/6327
```

I am currently able to get the http method. I want to try to parse the line for a message.

```
curl -X POST http://localhost:2300/messages/6327 gabriel, this is my message.
```

I want to parse "gabriel" as the sender and then the second part as the message. I just do not know how to extract that last part because $1 is POST $2 is myvar which is messages/6327 and $3 is HTTP/1.1. I tried using delimiters to find it as well but no luck. Basically I want to parse it and append it to a file. Here is the code I have:

```
#!/bin/bash

HTTP_200="HTTP/1.1 200 OK"
HTTP_404="HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found"
HTTP_400="HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request"

read myvar # reads the std in

http_method=`echo $myvar | awk '{print $1}'` 
resource=`echo $myvar | awk '{print $2}' | cut -d '/' -f 3`
status=`echo $myvar | awk '{print $2}' | cut -d '/' -f 2`

if [[ $status == "status" ]]
then
count=`cat messages.dat | wc -l`
echo ""
echo -e "$HTTP_200\nConent-Type: application/json\n\n{\"record_count\":\"$count\"}"
exit 2
fi

sender=`cat messages.dat | grep -E ^5101 | sort -t',' -k 3 | head -n 1 |  cut -d ',' -f 1 | awk '{print $1}'`

#recipient=`echo $resource | cut -d '/' -f 2`

valid_user=`cat /etc/passwd | grep $resource`
uid=`echo $valid_user | cut -d ':' -f 3`
get_sender=`cat messages.dat | grep -E ^$uid | sort -t',' -k 3 |head -n 1 |  cut -d ',' -f 2 | uniq`
valid_sender=`cat /etc/passwd | grep $get_sender`
username=`echo $valid_sender | cut -d ':' -f 1`
special_invalid_chars=`echo $resource | grep -E [[:punct:]]+`
get_posters_id=`id -u`

recipient=`cat messages.dat | grep -E ^$uid | sort -t',' -k 3 |  cut -d ',' -f 1 | uniq`     # | awk '{print $1}'`
time_stamp=`cat messages.dat | grep -E ^$uid | sort -t',' -k 3 | head -n 1 | cut -d ',' -f 3 | uniq`
time=`date --rfc-3339=seconds -d @$time_stamp`
message=`cat messages.dat | grep -E ^$uid | sort -t',' -k 3 | head -n 1 | cut -d ',' -f 4 | uniq` #| sort -t'.' -k 3`    #| awk '{print $1}'`

echo '' # This is to fix the issue of not printing $1 as we discovered in class

if [[ $special_invalid_chars ]]
then
    echo $HTTP_400
    exit 1
fi

while [[ $valid_user ]]
do
if [[ $http_method == POST ]]
then
    #echo ""

    post_time_stamp=`date +%s`
    #echo -e "\n1,$get_posters_id,$post_time_stamp, message to write " >> messages.dat
exit 1
fi
done

while [[ $http_method == GET ]]
do
if [[ $message == '' ]]
then
     echo -e "$HTTP_200\nContent-Type: application/json\n"
     echo "{}"
exit 2
fi
if [[ $valid_user ]]
then
    echo -e "{\n    \"sender\":  \"$username\",\n    \"message\": \"$message\",\n    \"timestamp\": \"$time\"\n}"

elif [[ $valid_user != true ]]
then
    echo $HTTP_404
    exit 1
fi
exit 1
done

#id -u gduarte 6327   then echo $? to get the code for invalid user
```

Here is my output currently for GET and the message.

```
    curl  http://localhost:3011/messages/5101
{
    "sender":  "jfoster",
    "message": " I might be late .",
    "timestamp": "2017-04-27 23:44:01-07:00"
}
```

And Lastly, Here is the file content that I am reading in and want to write to.
Data fields: recipient, sender, time stamp, and message respectively.

```
5031,5575,1493367738, This is a message for Cameron
5101,5618,1493361841, I might be late .
5139,5699,1493367845, Hello !!!
5101,6621,1493362341, I’m running late - don’t wait for me .
```

By the way, I am using ncat to test my shell script

Comment: Why don't you just change the usage of `curl`: `curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"sender":"gabriel","message":"this is my message"}' http://localhost:2300/messages/6327`

Comment: I typed in what you said and I could not get it to work.

Comment: When you use `curl` with -X, -H and -d, what do you get? Does the server receive request?

Comment: Yes, It waits for me to type something. I dont plan to change the header though as i am supposed to parse the message line the default way. Unless that is what m teacher means by "be able to tell the header when to end"